# Security Warning while using Delphi 10 Seattle

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

For a week or so now, while I use Delphi 10 Seattle, I'm constantly being nagged with the following Security Warning:

[image]

This seems to be caused the advertisement banner that's displayed with no project open, but it often bugs me while I'm working on a project.

Anybody experience this issue? It's not a breaking issue, but it's annoying. I'm guessing that there's some sort of security problem at Embarcadero servers, and I figured they'd have it fixed by now. But it's been long enough to start worrying about it.

Comment: You should contact Embarcadero directly about this sort of issue.

Comment: What is displayed when you click on `More Info` button?

Comment: This Q has nothing to do with programming, but merely with a software product. Please seek support at the vendor, as Embarcadero surely won't scan StackOverflow for bug reports. It may also "only" be a security issue for you, while Embarcadero's HTTP server does not serve any security issue - interpreting the content and rendering the a potential website on the client's end (you) is the point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is likely the 'welcome page' which is likely displaying an image via HTTP.  One way around this is to add a `-NP` command line parameter when starting the Delphi IDE to disable the welcome page.

You can also use the registry editor (Regedit) and find this key:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\17.0\Known IDE Packages`

Look for the key name `$(BDS)\Bin\startupide230.bpl` with the data description of `Start Page IDE Package`

You could simply delete this particular item, but one trick to disable a package is to prefix the text with an underscore.  So change the description to `_Start Page IDE Package` and then restart the IDE and it should not load the startup page and silence your warnings.

This should work for most recent versions of Delphi. (The BDS version number and BPL version number vary by version)